# RDP communication via C/C++

Tags: c++, rdp

I need to write a basic RDP client in C/C++, doesn't need GUI it can be CLI, it only needs to connect to specified hosts - if connection is successfull, to confirm it and if it isn't to output an error message like the pass is not correct. 
Can someone point me to somewhere so i can read more about this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the source for [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/) - A Remote Desktop Protocol Client for accessing Windows Terminal Services.

For a quick feel, view the source for [`tcp.c`](http://rdesktop.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rdesktop/rdesktop/trunk/tcp.c?view=markup): Protocol services - TCP layer.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the Windows Terminal Services API or also known as the [Remote Desktop Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383464(VS.85).aspx).